# Webpack dev server cannot get

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I' am using Webpack-4. Current behavior is that when webpack-dev-server is running, files under /build not get updated at all and it is showing the file directory.

If I delete the files under /build, webpack-dev-server is giving cannot get/. I assume, It should load them from memory.

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
   template: "./src/index.html",
   filename: "./index.html"
});

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/'),
},

module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["env","react"]
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    minimize: true
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    htmlPlugin
],
devServer: {       
    contentBase: "./build/",
    port: 5555
}
}
```

Comment: Please define entry point(entry: './main.js',) inside module.exports(above output config)

Comment: Webpack 4 has a default entry /src/index.js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A few tips that helped me understand and debug my local **webpack-dev-server** config:

1. To see where the files are served (in-memory) by webpack-dev-server,
   type `http://localhost:{yourport}/webpack-dev-server` in your browser. Then you can
   click on one of the file (link) and it will show you the route it's served
   from and the content of the file.
2. When you launch webpack-dev-server (i.e. using npm start), it shows you in the console where it's serving content from based on your `webpack.config.js` file. (See below for a detailed explanation)
3. If you want Hot Reload (I don't see why not), your need to specify it on the command line (In your package.json start script) and not in the config file. For some reason, putting it into the config file was not working. So use something like:

***package.json***

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --hot --inline"
},
```

***webpack.config.js Config***

```
...
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'scripts'),
},
...
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/scripts/',
    port: 8080
},
...
```

***Output***

```
 i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/    
 i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://localhost:8080/scripts/
 i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Workspace\WebSite\public
```

On line 2 of the output, notice that because of `contentBase` in the config, `http://localhost:8080/scripts/` actually points to `C:\Workspace\WebSite\public\scripts` on the disk. (And this is where webpack would also put its files :) !!!)

On the `publicPath` config, the trailing backslash is important.

Comment: I really wanted to give a big thank you for your answer! Hours of searches and the problem was from the `publicPath` was set by using `path.resolve('./dist')` which is the absolute path inside the app. That's why the browser couldn't see the compiled styles/scripts.  This answer should be marked as the full answer!!